# Ruby - How do you scan this text content?

Tags: ruby

I want an output like this: `["# foo\n\n1234\n\n", "# bar\n\nk23j4k2j4\nk23j4kj4\n\n", "# baz\n\nk2k2k2\n\n"]` with `scan` method from following text content.

```
content = '

# foo

1234

# bar

k23j4k2j4
k23j4kj4

# baz

k2k2k2

'
```

I tried the following code. But it didn't work as I think.

```
p content.scan(/^#.*/m)
# => ["# foo\n\n1234\n\n# bar\n\nk23j4k2j4\nk23j4kj4\n\n# baz\n\nk2k2k2\n\n"]
```

How do you solve this?

note: Alternatively You can use `split` or other methods instead of `scan`.

Comment: I do not know enough ruby to answer your question, but I would split on “#\n”.  Then I would remove the first result, prepend a # to each result, and do a search and replace to convert your newlines or \n and/or \r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` matchs all strings including `#`.
You have to exclude it.

```
content.scan(/^#[^#]*/m)
# => ["# foo\n\n1234\n\n", "# bar\n\nk23j4k2j4\nk23j4kj4\n\n", "# baz\n\nk2k2k2\n\n"]
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
content.scan(/#[^#]*/)
```

it matches `#` and anything else until you find `#` again

```
=> ["# foo\n\n1234\n\n", "# bar\n\nk23j4k2j4\nk23j4kj4\n\n", "# baz\n\nk2k2k2\n\n"]
```